# Devise already_authenticated flash message persists for more than 1 redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my routes.rb file, I defined the root path like this:

```
root 'users/sessions#new'
```

Then, in my ApplicationController, I have logic to redirect like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  return dashboard_path if user.normal_user?
  employee_dashboard_path
end
```

After signing in as a normal user, navigating to the root path (i.e. localhost:3000), I'm redirected to the `dashboard_path` as expected. However, when I click on an item on the dashboard and go to the item's show page, I see this flash message:

```
You are already signed in.
```

I'm confused, because shouldn't the flash message be flushed out after redirecting to the `dashboard_path`? I found out if I add code to display the flash message on the dashboard page, the flash message won't show up on the item's show page. The way I'm showing flash message is just simply this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
</div>
```

I know if I go to the `devise.en.yml` file and remove the `already_authenticated` message, the flash won't show up, but I don't want to do that because I do want to show this message for another type of user. Am I doing something wrong? Why does the flash message persist onto the item's show page and won't disappear after redirecting to the dashboard? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are calling the same action, you will see the flash message unless you call a new one

Comment: I called a new action. It's a different action but same controller, could that be why?

Comment: I think you are redirecting before the flash message comes up.Do your redirection after the flash message OR check both login and show action, there must be only one flash message present and NOT two.

Comment: I redirected after the flash message. I know the flash is present on the dashboard page because I tried to show flash message on that page, and I saw the flash for Devise sign in. After I removed that code though, the flash message shows after I navigate to the item's show page.

Comment: Can you try to use flash.now[:success]. This should do the trick

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I know it would, but I really just want to understand why it's happening...I'm really confused by this. I also realized I forgot to include that I'm on Rails 5.2.0 if that makes any difference.

Comment: NOPE..no major changes in context to flash messages in Rails 5...